# urlencode is not working when url path contains space

Tags: php, wordpress, url, curl, urlencode

I have a problem when fetch json data through url.

the url is `http://farmapi.fastway.org/v3/psc/lookup/MEL/Point%20cook/3030?LengthInCm=30&WidthInCm=30&HeightInCm=30&WeightInKg=4&api_key=MY_API_KEY`

I tried to encode Point Cook by using urlencode. but it is not working. However this url can work when you paste it to browser directly.

the code I used to send url is:

```
$curl = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP/' . phpversion());
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
echo '<pre>post_request response' . print_r( $response, true) . '</pre>';
if (curl_errno( $curl )) {
    $this->response = curl_error( $curl );
    return $this->response;
    curl_close( $curl );
}

curl_close( $curl );
```

or this:

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method'    => 'POST',
    'timeout'   => 70,
    'sslverify' => 0
    ) );
```

Does anyone can help me out of this problem or give me some possible solutions? I will really appreciate it.

Comment: *"it is not working"* - you should make this part much more clear. What did happen? What have you expected instead? Do you even get some error message? And yes, the SPACE character is a reserved character in URLs, you need to encode it (this is what the browser does when you put that in).

Comment: The fact that it works in a browser when you just click a link means that you don't need the method to be `POST`. Also, in your curl code that you show, you're not actually executing the request.

Comment: if i didn't encode `point cook`, the error message is 400 bad request.
but if I did encode, the error message is 404 Not Found

Comment: For hakre's answer, I did what you said, but it give 404 error. that's what I really confused. but it works directly in browser.

Comment: How do you use `urlencode`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank your for hakre and Colin Morelli. From answers your guys provided, I find the real problem in the code.

First thing is to use `rawurlencode`. this function turns `point cook` into `point%20cook`, which is correct format. `urlencode` function turns `point cook` into `point+cook` which is not acceptable on server-side.

The second problem, that Colin Morelli mentioned, is that I used worry method to send url. I should use GET instead of POST.

Thanks guys!!!